# DataFormatString ASP.NET MVC и input type = "number" не принимает запятую

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Вопрос вроде бы простой, мне известно, что input type Number принимает точку и игнорирует запятую, но у меня проблема в следующем:
Модель в ASP.NET MVC:

```
{
    public class EditMaterial
    {
        public long rowid { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Смена 3, т.")]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:F3}")]
        public double smena3 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Как видно используется форматирование в String типа double с тремя знаками после разделителя (нужно именно так), но по факту с моими региональными настройками получаем разделитель запятую, а не точку.
В дальнейшем форма типа number не принимает эти данные и форма остаётся пустой.

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.smena3, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.smena3, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @type = "number", @min = "0", @step = "0.001" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.smena3, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
</div>
```

Как решить эту проблему, не изменяя тип данных double в модели?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно изменить региональные настройки для одной страницы, для этого в контроллере, который вызывает необходимую страницу нужно прописать:

```
CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
```